# LinkedIn : Getting basic infos of users I interact with via messaging or connect request

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I am building a Node.js backend for a BI webapp that requires to be connected to Linkedin to get basic infos of the LinkedIn users I interact with (full name, current position and the interaction date).

I want to track the following interactions :

- The LinkedIn user send me a connect request
- I send a connect request to the LinkedIn user
- The LinkedIn user send me a message for the first time
- I send the LinkedIn user a message for the first time

I already found this very useful **scraper** allowing me to get profile infos given the profile url. https://github.com/linkedtales/scrapedin

So now I would need to find a way to automatically get profile urls of users I interact with, in addition to getting the interaction date.

Any idea ? Any kind of help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After [authenticated](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) your app make a request to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json
. You can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) as your client. Sample response according to [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) would be like this:

```
{
  "firstName": "Frodo",
  "headline": "Jewelery Repossession in Middle Earth",
  "id": "1R2RtA",
  "lastName": "Baggins",
  "siteStandardProfileRequest": {
    "url": "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=…"
  }
}
```

Then is you have stored above response in `response` variable:

```
const userProfileUrl = JSON.parse(response).siteStandardProfileRequest.url
```